# Wordpress headless with Gatsby or Next, locally

Tags: wordpress, next.js, localhost, gatsby, headless-cms

Im running WordPress locally on my network, and building sites in Next or Gatsby, using wordpress as a headless CMS. But can I somehow then put up my sites to say Netlify, without having to connect from the onlinepage on Netlify to my locally running wordpress? My guess is it doesnt work with Next? But is it possible in Gatsby to build the whole page locally and then add the site to my netlify account? Can you save the content from Wordpress as a json file or something and use that with Next on netlify to get it to work. I just want to use Wordpress on my own, to add content but doesnt want an connection with the outside world to my own "homeserver"...

Everything works for me locally, but Im not really shure how build works with Next and Gatsby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible with Gatsby.
You just need your Wordpress CMS to build. Once it is build, you can run it anywhere without the need of Wordpress or any other backend server.